# How to pass two value in to HyperLinkColumn on asp.net 1.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the code:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="dataGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dataGrid1_ItemDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="Valid,CouponCode" 
         DataTextField="Valid" 
          HeaderText="Enable / Disable"
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="?id={0}orgValue={1}" />
      </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

In newer version of .net they got `DataNavigateUrlFields`, but in asp.net only have `DataNavigateUrlField`. (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlfields(v=vs.80).aspx)

So, how can I pass two value into `HyperLinkColumn`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass multiple parameters then convert that column to itemtemplate hyperlink column and then pass multiple parameters using navigateURL property. Like

```
<asp:datagrid id="dataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Order">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Hyperlink runat= "server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductName").tostring%>' 
                          NavigateUrl='<%# "page2.aspx?Name=" & DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"ProductName").tostring & _   
                          "&ProductID=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductID").tostring %>' ID="ProductName"/>   
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateColumn>                                    
         </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

You have to do something like that,Hope it works..